# lock-free job queue (multiple read/write) - review requested

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, atomic

I was looking for a *simple lock-free job-queue which can be used in a generic way, cross-platform.

<sub>* no external dependencies, only few calls to interface, no exotic compiler tricks which may break from compiler to compiler, preferably header only.</sub>

Either I suck at googling, or this isn't available. ( they are not mutually exclusive, but you get the point )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. It should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As was also suggested by @Edward, this is now available on codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46722/lock-free-job-queue-without-size-restriction-multiple-read-write

Comment: Additionally to this being off-topic: The title and question do not match. The title asks for code review (off-topic, belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com), the question asks for an implementation (off-topic, asking for library etc.).

Answer (score 2):

In push function, Let mark two point:

```
Line 1: start_.compare_exchange_strong( tmp, newnode );
Line 2: node_ptr prev_end = end_.exchange( newnode ); // and set next pointer
```

Now, consider two threads calling push:

```
                start   end     a.next  b.next
Begin           null    null    -       -
TA.push(a) - 1  a       null    null    null
TB.push(b) - 1  a       null    null    null
TB.push(b) - 2  a       b       null    null
TA.push(a) - 2  a       a       null    a
```

As you can see, b is lost in the list.

Comment: It looks like this is unique to an empty list, I guess the line following 2 should assign end_ to start_->next if it is empty, whenever prev_end was a nullptr